# Is there a solution to this React-native error

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation, npm-install

I just took my first steps with expo-react , after installing "réact-navigation" if I try to run the project with "npm start", voilà ce que j'ai trouvé **unable *unable to find expo in this project - have you run yarn /npm install yet*

Comment: Check to make sure you're in the correct directory. Also make sure that you've run npm install in your project as well as that the expo package is present in your package.json

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first check if there is an expo npm package in the package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Run "npm install" first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).